# Drupal 8 Twitter doesnt appear for anonymous, only admin

Tags: twitter, drupal, feed

What could be the problem when my twitter block only appears for admin and doesnt for anonymous users. I have set block permission for both anonymous and authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is i had to run the js library locally. This is my script:

1. Open you *****.libraries.yml and add :

```
global-scripts:
    version: VERSION
    js: 
      js/twitter/widgets.js: {}   
    dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
```

2. Open your ****.info.yml and add under libraries:

```
libraries:
  - ****/global-scripts
```